# Django DetailView Template default field value not working

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, detailview

I have a problem using the '|default' in django templates.

If I do this (it works):

```
<tr>
    <td>{% trans 'NAMEOFTHEFIELD' %}:</td>
    <td>{{ object.nameofthefield|default:"Not informed" }}</td>
</tr>
```

But I have many many fields so I do:

```
{% for name, value in object.get_fields %}
  {% if value %}
    <tr>
        <td>{% trans name %}:</td>
        <td>{{ value|default:"Not informed" }}</td>

    </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, the default value is not working, and it shows "None" instead of "Not informed" in the template.

Do you know an easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are converting to `str` in `get_fields` method of model. If that is not true, please post your `get_fields` method.

Comment: I was using value_to_string then I changed to _get_val_from_obj:

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field._get_val_from_obj(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]

^.^